# How to install mdbootstrap into an existing Angular 9 project?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, angular-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

[mdbootstrap docs](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/)
explains how to create a completely new project with md-bootstrap, but what about an existing project? [This article](https://medium.com/@reshailawan/how-to-install-md-bootstrap-in-your-angular-9-project-7eadd45a758d) on Medium proposes 2 different way, involving editing of *angular.json* file, which I'd prefer to avoid. Is there an easier way?

Comment: The easier way would be to add the mdbootstrap with schematics but it is only possible if the library owner has made it available in the repository. For example, ng-bootstrap library could be easily added using the command `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and it does not require any configuration changes manually.

Comment: The instructions will be the same for the existing project. You need to install dependencies and update angular.json/module files accordingly. The easiest way would be to use automatic installation with `ng add angular-bootstrap-md`. Modifying angular.json file is a common way to add global dependencies